# Databinding breaks after reloading DBcontext

Tags: wpf, vb.net, entity-framework-6

I have the following ViewModel, bound to a DataGrid in my view using `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsViewSource.View}"`:

```
Public Class DataTableViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase


    Private _dataContext As DbContext

    Private _items As IList
    Private _itemsType As Type
    Private _contextType As Type
    Private _itemsViewSource As CollectionViewSource
    Private _itemsView As ListCollectionView

    'Commands
    Private _refreshTableCommand As ICommand

    Public ReadOnly Property RefreshTableCommand As ICommand
        Get
            If _refreshTableCommand Is Nothing Then
                _refreshTableCommand = New RelayCommand(AddressOf ExecuteRefreshTable, AddressOf CanExecuteRefreshTable)
            End If
            Return _refreshTableCommand
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Function CanExecuteRefreshTable() As Boolean
        'This command can always run.
        Return True
    End Function

    Private Sub ExecuteRefreshTable()
        Me.RefreshTable()
    End Sub

    Public Property Items As IList
        Get
            Return Me._items
        End Get
        Set(value As IList)
            _items = value
            MyBase.OnPropertyChanged("Items")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ItemsViewSource As CollectionViewSource
        Get
            Return Me._itemsViewSource
        End Get
        Set(value As CollectionViewSource)
            Me._itemsViewSource = value
            MyBase.OnPropertyChanged("ItemsViewSource")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ItemsView As ListCollectionView
        Get
            Return Me._itemsView
        End Get
        Set(value As ListCollectionView)
            Me._itemsView = value
            MyBase.OnPropertyChanged("ItemsView")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property DataContext As DbContext
        Get
            Return Me._dataContext
        End Get
    End Property


    Public ReadOnly Overrides Property IsDirty As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me._dataContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub RefreshTable()

        NewDataContext()

    End Sub

    Private Sub NewDataContext()
        If Me._dataContext IsNot Nothing Then
            Me._dataContext.Dispose()
        End If
        Me._dataContext = Activator.CreateInstance(_contextType)
        Me._dataContext.Set(_itemsType).Load
        Me.Items = _dataContext.Set(_itemsType).Local
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(displayName As String, contextType As Type, recordType As Type)
        MyBase.DisplayName = displayName

        Me._itemsType = recordType
        Me._contextType = contextType

        NewDataContext()

        Me._itemsViewSource = New CollectionViewSource
        Me.ItemsViewSource.Source = Me.Items
        Me.ItemsView = CType(Me.ItemsViewSource.View, ListCollectionView)
        Me.ItemsView.Filter = New Predicate(Of Object)(AddressOf FilterByString)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The code functions perfectly until the `RefreshTable()` method is called at which point the databinding seems to break. Any new data from the database *is* loaded into the ViewModel and is available in the Items list, however the new data is not shown in the datagrid and any changes made by the user in the DataGrid are not reflected by the DBContext.ChangeTracker.

What am I missing?

**Edit:**
Upon further testing, the problem seems to be somehow related to the CollectionViewSource; if I bind directly to the Items property, updated records are properly shown in the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I've been staring at the screen too long.
The CollectionViewSource needs to be rebuilt as well and the DataGrid notified via OnPropertyChanged("ItemsViewSource").

Fix:

```
Private Sub RefreshTable()

    NewDataContext()

    Me._itemsViewSource = New CollectionViewSource
    Me.ItemsViewSource.Source = Me.Items
    Me.ItemsView = CType(Me.ItemsViewSource.View, ListCollectionView)
    Me.ItemsView.Filter = New Predicate(Of Object)(AddressOf FilterByString)

    'Let WPF know the data changed in the ViewModel
    OnPropertyChanged("ItemsViewSource")


End Sub
```